# how to detect face landmarks other than iPhone X using vision framework

Tags: ios, vision

I have observed couple of applications like SnapChat , tik-tok who are using face landmarks feature to show some fancy photo editings on most of iPhones but vision framework supports only from iPhone X. Could anyone help me how are they able todo. are there any alternatives other than vision framework to detect mouth open, closing eyes etc.

Comment: Do you mean, How can I use those frameworks from other phones? (iPhone 7 for instance?)  As far as I know, that is not possible.

Comment: Yes this is not possible , which framework will allow me to do the same on iPhone 7 and 8

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Vision Framework on an iPhone 7 and it's working perfectly, please see this example project for more informations:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/tracking_the_user_s_face_in_real_time